# Take derivative of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take the derivative of a dataframe row-wise. This is simply the difference: `df_derived(i,j) = df(i,j)- df(i,j-1)`. Dataframe given below:

```py
    GRD1    GRD2    GRD3    GRD4    GRD5    GRD6    GRD7
0   1       6       5.0     9.0     1.0     7.0     9
1   5       8       NaN     8.0     NaN     NaN     2
2   7       8       NaN     NaN     NaN     2.0     6
```

I am looking for:

```py
    GRD1    GRD2    GRD3    GRD4    GRD5    GRD6    GRD7
0   NaN     5.0     -1      4.0     -8.0    6.0     2.0
1   NaN     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     4.0
```

But when I do: `df.apply('diff',axis=1)`, result is different:

```py
    GRD1    GRD2    GRD3    GRD4    GRD5    GRD6    GRD7
0   NaN     5.0     NaN     4.0     -8.0    6.0     3.0
1   NaN     3.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     -6.0
2   NaN     1.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     -2.0
```

Notice column GR3 and GRD7 are different.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try cast all columns to `float`

```
df_final = df.astype(float).diff(axis=1)

Out[65]:
   GRD1  GRD2  GRD3  GRD4  GRD5  GRD6  GRD7
0   NaN   5.0  -1.0   4.0  -8.0   6.0   2.0
1   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```

Comment: Wow (Facepalm). Thanks.

Comment: @Kaisar: You are welcome. You are not alone. This issue hit me in the past. That's why I know the solution so fast :D

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `numpy` `diff`

```
df[:]=np.hstack([np.ones((len(df),1))*np.nan,np.diff(df.values)])
df
   GRD1  GRD2  GRD3  GRD4  GRD5  GRD6  GRD7
0   NaN   5.0  -1.0   4.0  -8.0   6.0   2.0
1   NaN   3.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   4.0
```